# meson: copy script to build directory

Tags: shell, command, file-copying, meson-build

I have as tests both C and shell source files. Meson [unit tests](https://mesonbuild.com/Unit-tests.html) are expected to be run from build directory. Compiled binaries from my C sources I get copied into build directory automatically (specified as `executable()`), how to copy there shell scripts?

Or should I run / source them from source directory, e.g.

```
test = join_paths(meson.source_root(), 'tests/run.sh')
run_command(test, "--foo", "bar")
```

Or use [`find_program()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#find_program)?

```
test = find_program('run.sh')
run_command(test, "--foo", "bar")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more canonical way of doing that would be using "dummy" `custom_target`:

```
scipt_name = 'run.sh'
custom_target('copy script',
  input : script_name,
  output :  script_name,
  command : ['cp', '@INPUT@', '@OUTPUT@'],
  install : false,
  build_by_default : true)
```

This is better because it will get executed, i.e. copied when updated; and if you add this to `meson.build` in **`tests`** folder - no paths manipulations needed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, [`find_program()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#find_program) searches in the system `PATH`, thus not suitable. Probably copying files to the build directory will be better:

```
src = join_paths(meson.source_root(), 'tests/run.sh')
dest = join_paths(meson.build_root(), 'tests')
message('copying @0@ to @1@ ...'.format(src, dest))
run_command('cp', src, dest)
```